# Запись в массив по кнопке

Tags: php

Добрый вечер.У меня есть на сайте кнопка  Test. Как сделать так, например 3 разных человека нажимают ее, к ним присвоены разные индексы. Первому - 001 Второму 002 Третьему 003. И эти индексы записывались в массив. И когда этот массив заполнен полностью, то есть три записи, сработала например функция

```
echo "Запись прошла успешна";
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут у вас две подзадачи.
Однозначно идентифицировать конкретного посетителя (я так понимаю регистрации нет). Используйте,в зависимости от деталей задачи,cookie или переменные сессии. Записывайте туда уникальный идентификатор, если кукис/переменная не существует.

Вторая подзадача гененрировать уникальный ИД. Тут, опять же, зависит от задачи. Как вариант - берете текущее время,Ip посетителя и получаете хэш от этих значений. Вероятность совпадений мала. 
Второй вариант, записывать соответствие в базу (SQL или файл).

Если посетители должны знать друг о друге то надо записывать информацию в базу или файл (можно еще в общюю память, например)

ТЧтобы все увидели надпись "Заполнен". Вы должны предусмотреть либо получение обновленной информации. Самое простое: периодическое обновление страницы. Правильное - AJAX (при чем тут есть варианты)

Comment: У пользователя будет свой идентификатор он его знает. Он видит кнопку и форму там. Вводит в форму свой ИД он отправляется в файл test.php  и записываться в массив в нулевую ячейку. Потом другой пользователь зашел на сайт ввел туда свой ИД и форма опять отправляет в test.php и его ИД уже записывается в 1 ячейку массива и так третий делает. Потом идет рандом массива. И потом надо после рандома удалять все записи из массива чтобы он был опять чистым для записей.

Answer (score 0):

тут аякс

```js
<script> 
$(window).load(function() { //говорим скрипту что он сработает когда вся страница загрузится
  var ID = [];//оббозначаем переменную для массива
  $('.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.width').click(function() {//ловим клик
    ID.push($(this).data('id'));//записываем результат кликов в массив
    console.log(ID);
  });//что выдадет консоль точнее масив
    $('.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.width').click(function(e) { //ловим клик
    $("#basket").show("slow"); // показываем как откроется форма
  });
  // показываем как откроется форма
  $('.compare_basket').click(function(e) { //ловим клик
    $(".compare_basket").hide("slow");

    });// показываем как откроется форма
  $('#basket').click(function(e) { //ловим клик
    $(".compare_basket").show("slow");
    
    console.log(ID); //что выдадет консоль
    $.ajax({ // сам ajax запрос
    url: "myscript.php", // обработчик на php 
    data: {id: ID}, // даные которые передатся
    type: "POST", // метод
    success: function(response){
     $("#ajaxDivId_1").html(response); 
     $("#ajaxDivId_2").html(response.id_2); 
     $("#ajaxDivId_3").html(response.id_3); 
     }, // если запрос удачный выводим то что вернул скрипт php
    error: function(er){ alert(er); }, // если запрос не удался выводим ошибку
  })
      .done(function(data) { //отладочный запрос по которому заносятся данные 
       // выводим отладочную информацию

      });


  });
}) 
</script>
```

```html
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $idd = $_POST['id'];
    


    $result = count($idd);
   
    
    
    $id = array();

        if (count($result) == 1)
       
        {
       
       $id_1 = (current($idd));
       echo json_encode(array('id_1'=>$id_1));

       
        }



        if (count($result) < 3)
       
        {
       next($idd);
       $id_2 = (current($idd));
       echo json_encode(array('id_2'=>$id_2));

       
        

     if ($result < 3)
        
        {

        $err[] = "Можно сранивать не более трех модель";
        
        }
    
    elseif (count($err) > 4) {
        echo json_encode($err);
    }
?>}
```

html

```html
<div class="compare_basket" id="compare_basket">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4" id="ajaxDivId_1"></div>
<div class="col-md-4" id="ajaxDivId_2"></div>
<div class="col-md-4" id="ajaxDivId_3"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="basket" id="basket">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-basket">Сравнить выбраное</button>
</div>
<button data-id=1 id='basket-block' val=1 class='btn btn-primary btn-lg width'>

                          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'>
                          </span>
                          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'>
                          </span>Сравнить

                    </button>
```